# How to select a certain element with jQuery by traversing to parent to back to child?

Tags: jquery, select

I have the following code.

```
<div class="container">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" class="id" />
     <div class="inner">
          <a href="#" class="link">link</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

So I am trying to get the hidden id value when the anchor tag is clicked.  And this is the following code I tried but didn't work.

```
jQuery("a.link").click(function() {
     var id = jQuery(this).parents(".container").children("input.id").val();
     alert(id);
});
```

Not even sure if that is the best way to select what I want...Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/6nrGn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
jQuery(".link").live('click',function() {
     var id = jQuery(this).parents(".container").find(".id").val();
     alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - although I don't think live is needed but your find() function gave me an idea...So I replaced children with find and it works as I wanted.

Comment: Kanishka, .live() is not recommended anymore. It was once recommended to use .delegate() instead, and it is currently recommended to use the new .on() function from jQ 1.7 onward.

Comment: @Greg Pettit  . thank you very much . i knew that .but any way thank you very much............... :D

Answer (score 1):

Is that hidden input tag functional, or purely present for inspecting when somebody clicks your link?  An alternative to this would be to output the value you want into the anchor tag itself, using the `rel` attribute, and eliminate the hidden input.

Make your HTML output this:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="inner">
          <a href="#" class="link" rel="123">link</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then your jQuery is this:

```
jQuery("a.link").click(function() {
     var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
     alert(id);
});
```

If that `<input>` tag isn't functional, this will simplify both your HTML and your jQuery too.

Comment: Don't abuse the `rel` attribute this way. Use a `data-id` attribute and retrieve it using `$(this).data('id')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a.link").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).parent().siblings(".id").val();
});
```

If you want to find it by the input type, you can do this:

```
$("a.link").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().siblings("input[type='hidden']").val());
});
```